# Error installing app on Android 2.3 device

Tags: android, coronasdk

I build an app using these instructions: http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/build-android-devices-windows. When I connect my device with USB cable and transfer the .APK file. And when I try to install the app, I get an error message which simple says that the app has not been installed or something like that. The app(game) is working fine in the Corona Simulator but not in the real device.

This is the app - https://www.dropbox.com/s/j6jft1y81klh8gz/BlackJack.apk

(but actually I'm getting this error in my device whatever app I trying to install).

And I'm using Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360, android 2.3.5 (Gingerbread).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What does the log say? Install LogCat and post the result here.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Nicolas, I'm using Corona with Outlaw Text Editor. I don't know how can I post LogCat in this case because I don't see any Log in here. It's not Eclipse. 

Marek, it just says what the "App cannot be installed" when I trying to install .APK file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems come's from the processor of the phone it uses ARMv6 processor which does not support by the new SDK Build of Corona

see this link it has the same problem as yours http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/21994-resolved-armv6-support/

Comment: Yes, that was the case. I'm using ARMv6 processor. It's kinda sad because I think that a lot of people still using this processor in their smart phones and they can't play games made with Corona. Thanks for the answer, devfar.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you receive the error no matter what app you are trying to install, make sure that you have enabled `Unknown sources` on your device in order to be able to install APK files directly. This location of this setting is usually found in the `Security` setting.